# mysqli::error() is not detected

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm beginner in php and I have a problem that I can not explain by myself.. I have two files: the first one index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input name="file" type="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Wyslij" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the second one upload.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','kursphp','products');

    $name= $db->real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $type=$db->real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['type']);
    $data=$db->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    $size=intval($_FILES['file']['size']);

    //question

    $query= "INSERT INFO files(name,type,size,data,created) VALUES ('{$name}','{$type}','{$size}','{$data}',NOW())";

    $result=$db->query($query);

    if($result){
    echo "File saved";
    } else {
        echo $db->error();
    }

    $db->close();
}

?>
```

When I upload some file, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() in D:\wamp\www\php_z\upload\upload.php on line 20
```

I don't know why I get this kind of error because as I declared: db is an object of mysqli. I read in documentation of PHP that

```
mysqli::$error -- mysqli_error — Returns a string description of the last error
```

So there is method such `error()`.. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: `INSERT INFO files` you sure about that? Coding on an iPhone? lol typo right? They always are.

Comment: omg i made a mistake INSERT INTO files, now it works correctly. I'm coding in VS using free extension of PHP for VS 2013 its very bad i must say .. cuz of that i make this kind of stupid mistakes.. btw thx!!

Comment: You're welcome. So, problem solved I hope? Would you like me to post an answer for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a few errors.

The first being:

```
INSERT INFO files
         ^
```

which should read as `INTO` and not `INFO`. The `T` and `F` are close to each other on the keyboard, so that can happen.

Then there's `echo $db->error();` which should read as `echo $db->error;`

This should be an object oriented style and not a procedural style.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php**

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a function, its a variable. Access it like this:

```
echo $db->error;
```

<sup>[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method named error.  There is a variable named error.  Thus, change

`echo $db->error();`

to

`echo $db->error;`